# Using JQuery, how do I check that at least one textbox is not empty?

Tags: jquery

Sounds simple but it's giving me grief:

Tried this:

```
function validateAddress() {

    if (!($('<%=txtPlaceName.ClientID%>').val() === "")
         || !($('<%=txtStreet.ClientID%>').val() === "")
         || !($('<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>').val() === "")
         || !($('<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>').val() === "")) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and this:

```
function validateAddress() {

    if ($('<%=txtPlaceName.ClientID%>').val().length > 0
         || $('<%=txtStreet.ClientID%>').val().length > 0
         || $('<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>').val().length > 0
         || $('<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>').val().length > 0) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

but neither seem to work, am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Why even use the multiple conditions in the if?  Why not just select all textareas on your page and use .each to iterate over them return true if any length > 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the hash mark to select something by id.  Try:

```
function validateAddress() {

    if ($('#<%=txtPlaceName.ClientID%>').val().length > 0
         || $('#<%=txtStreet.ClientID%>').val().length > 0
         || $('#<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>').val().length > 0
         || $('#<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>').val().length > 0) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: case closed, I seem to forget that a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @SLC - While this does solve the issue, you can make your life much easier, check out my alternative using a class.  You can also move all your code outside the page with this method.

Comment: @Nick - While your idea appears tidier, class should really be used for CSS, when pages are written and passed to the design team they might mess it up!

Answer (score 3):

For a [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you need a `#`, like this:

```
$('#<%=txtPlaceName.ClientID%>').val().length
```

But the quicker way could be to give them a class, e.g. `CssClass="checkMe"`, then check those elements:

```
function validateAddress() {
  return $('.checkMe[value!=""]').length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning that up.  Every time a programmer regurgitates something senselessly, god kills a kitten.

Comment: Rather than using a CSS class, you could also use the HTML5 Web Forms 2.0 attribute "required", which will be more semantically correct and future-compatible

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the "#" in your jquery selectors for ids.  Try this:

```
if ($('#<%=txtPlaceName.ClientID%>').val().length > 0 
     || $('#<%=txtStreet.ClientID%>').val().length > 0 
     || $('#<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>').val().length > 0 
     || $('#<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>').val().length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

are you adding # to the ID of the element when you check it, in other words, is the produced text like this:

```
$('#IDOfElement').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using classes to group functionality, so for your example give each of the element a class of address then your function would be:

```
function validateAddress() {
  $('.address').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```